# Sort data from two delimited strings containing times with different formats

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, time

I am looking for a way to combine multiple movie showtimes into a single string. The data we get from our source has a couple of instances of a specific movie playing at a specific theater on a specific day, but having two listings in the XML because the theater serves alcohol and is playing the movie in a regular theater and the boozy theater.

Here are two examples of movie showtime strings that we get from our data source:

1. 8:00, 10:30, 11:40 PM
2. (11:20 AM), (4:40), 8:00, 11:40 PM

- ()'s denote a matinee showing.

With those showtime strings, I need it to look like this:

- (11:20 AM), (4:40), 8:00, 10:30, 11:40 PM

I have no problem removing duplicates from the strings (8:00, for example), but I am struggling with how to best combine the strings into a single, cohesive unit.

Does anybody have any recommendations on how to do this in PHP? The server this needs to run on has 5.3.something

Edit - Code
I don't think this is going to make a whole bunch of sense, because it is part of a larger script I'm editing

```
//Make a unique key so we can check if a movie listing already exists for this combo
$showtimesKey = implode('_', array(
    (string)$currentShowTime->theater_id,
    (string)$currentShowTime->movie_id,
    (string)$currentListing['date']
));
if (!isset($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey])) {
    foreach (explode(", ", trim($currentListing->showtimes)) as $time) {
        $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey][$time] = $time;
    }
} else {
    $previousTimes = $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey];
    foreach (explode(", ", trim($currentListing->showtimes)) as $time) {
        $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey][$time] = $time;
    }
    natsort($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey]);
    //sort($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey], SORT_STRING);
    $currentListing->showtimes = $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey];
}
```

Comment: Please post your code effort to show what you already did.

Comment: okay, there is now code pertaining to this. None of the PHP sort functions seem to have what I am looking for, so I'm more looking for guidance in how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue this way, though it seems a bit cumbersome and over-engineered. But I couldn't come up with a good way to keep AM's, Matinee's, and regular PM showtimes in the correct order.

```
    $showtimesKey = implode('_', array(
        (string)$currentShowTime->theater_id,
        (string)$currentShowTime->movie_id,
        (string)$currentListing['date']
    ));
    if (!isset($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey])) {
        $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] = (string) $currentListing->showtimes;
    } else {
        $previousTimes = $currentTimes = array();
        foreach (explode(", ", trim($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey])) as $time) {
            $previousTimes[$time] = $time;
        }
        foreach (explode(", ", trim($currentListing->showtimes)) as $time) {
            $currentTimes[$time] = $time;
        }
        //Just in case we need to get at unedited time arrays
        $original_times = array(
            'previous' => $previousTimes,
            'current' => $currentTimes
        );

        $am = array();
        $pm = array('matinee' => array(), 'full_price' => array());

        //Previous Times
        if ($position = strpos(implode(",", $previousTimes), "AM")) {
            $joined_times = implode(", ", $previousTimes);
            list($tmp_am, $tmp_pm) = explode(" AM)", $joined_times);
            $tmp_am = str_replace(array("(", ")"), '', $tmp_am);
            foreach (explode(", ", $tmp_am) as $time) {
                $am[$time] = $time;
            }

            //Set $previousTimes to only the PM times
            $previousTimes = array();
            foreach (explode(", ", $tmp_pm) as $time) {
                if (empty($time)) continue;
                $previousTimes[$time] = $time;
            }
        }

        foreach ($previousTimes as $time) {
            $time = str_replace(" PM", '', $time);
            if ((strpos($time, "(") !== false) || (strpos($time, ")") !== false)) {
                //We are removing the parentesis from the time so a) we can make sure we aren't duplicating any and b) so the array key is just the time
                $only_time = str_replace(array("(", ")"), '', $time);
                $pm['matinee'][$only_time] = $only_time;
            } else {
                $pm['full_price'][$time] = $time;
            }
        }

        //Current Times
        if ($position = strpos(implode(",", $currentTimes), "AM")) {
            $joined_times = implode(", ", $currentTimes);
            list($tmp_am, $tmp_pm) = explode(" AM)", $joined_times);
            $tmp_am = str_replace(array("(", ")"), '', $tmp_am);
            foreach (explode(", ", $tmp_am) as $time) {
                $am[$time] = $time;
            }

            //Set $currebtTimes to only the PM times
            $currentTimes = array();
            foreach (explode(", ", $tmp_pm) as $time) {
                if (empty($time)) continue;
                $currentTimes[$time] = $time;
            }
        } 

        foreach ($currentTimes as $time) {
            $time = str_replace(" PM", '', $time);
            if ((strpos($time, "(") !== false) || (strpos($time, ")") !== false)) {
                //We are removing the parentesis from the time so a) we can make sure we aren't duplicating any and b) so the array key is just the time
                $only_time = str_replace(array("(", ")"), '', $time);
                $pm['matinee'][$only_time] = $only_time;
            } else {
                $pm['full_price'][$time] = $time;
            }
        }

        natsort($am); natsort($pm['matinee']); natsort($pm['full_price']);

        if (!empty($am)) {
            $last = end($am);
            $am[$last] .= " AM";
        }

        if (!empty($pm['full_price'])) {
            $last = end($pm['full_price']);
            $pm['full_price'][$last] .= " PM";
        } else {
            //Only try and tack PM onto the last matinee showing if there actually are matinee showings
            if (!empty($pm['matinee'])) {
                $last = end($pm['matinee']);
                $pm['matinee'][$last] .= " PM";
            }
        }

        foreach ($am as $key => $value) {
            $am[$key] = "(" . $value . ")";
        }
        foreach ($pm['matinee'] as $key => $value) {
            $pm['matinee'][$key] = "(" . $value . ")";
        }

        $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] = '';
        if (!empty($am)) {
            $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] = implode(", ", $am);
        }
        if (!empty($pm['matinee'])) {
            if (!empty($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey])) {
                $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] .= ", ";
            }
            $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] .= implode(", ", $pm['matinee']);
        }
        if (!empty($pm['full_price'])) {
            if (!empty($justShowtimes[$showtimesKey])) {
                $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] .= ", ";
            }
            $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey] .= implode(", ", $pm['full_price']);
        }
        $currentListing->showtimes = $justShowtimes[$showtimesKey];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
$string1 = "8:00, 10:30, 11:40 PM";
$string2 = "(11:20 AM), (4:40), 8:00, 11:40 PM ";

$fullString = $string1.",".$string2;
$splittedString = split(",",$fullString);

$times = array();
foreach($splittedString as $id=>$timeStr) {
        $timeStr = (strpos($timeStr,'('))?str_replace(array("(",")"),"",$timeStr)." -1 DAY":$timeStr;
        $time = strtotime($timeStr);
        $times[$time] = $splittedString[$id];
}

ksort($times);
$orderedString = implode(",",$times);
echo $orderedString ;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Concatenate the two strings with a comma-space as glue.
2. Split the consolidated string on comma-spaces and remove duplicates.
3. Populate a new array of timestamps (or datetime objects if you prefer) after standardizing the format of the time expression.  I am electing to trim any leading/trailing parentheses then padding the right-side of the string to a length of 8 with " PM" so that any time ambiguity defaults to after noon.
4. Sort the times array by the sorting array and it's all done.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jm2SP))

```
$string1 = "8:00, 10:30, 11:40 PM";
$string2 = "(11:20 AM), (4:40), 8:00, 11:40 PM";

$times = array_unique(explode(', ', "$string1, $string2"));
$sorter = [];
foreach ($times as $time) {
    $sorter[] = strtotime(str_pad(trim($time, '()'), 8, " PM"));
}
array_multisort($sorter, $times);
var_export(implode(', ', $times));
```

Output:

```
'(11:20 AM), (4:40), 8:00, 10:30, 11:40 PM'
```